# Openldap: how to add an acl for cn=config starting by slapd.conf?

Tags: openldap

I usually configure from 0 openldap servers
using slapd.conf and then converting to ldif

```
slaptest -f /etc/openldap/slapd.conf -F /etc/slapd.d
```

Works fine,but i want to add an acl wich must result like this in

```
/etc/slapd.d/cn\=config.ldif

olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.base="cn=Manager,dc=ldap1,dc=server,dc=local" write
olcAccess: {1}to * by dn.exact=gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external
 ,cn=auth write by * read
```

The question is: how to wrote those acl in slapd.conf?
I put this

```
access to *
        by dn.base="cn=Manager,dc=ldap1,dc=server,dc=local" write
        by * read
```

but create acl only on db files and not  on  /etc/slapd.d/cn\=config.ldif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editing acls on

```
/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={0}config.ldif
```

give me the permission to search with ldapsearch

And this is correct syntax with old slapd.conf

```
database config
access to *
    by dn.exact="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" manage
    by * none
```